# Where are vector elements written after .push_back()? C++

Tags: c++, vector

I have some code:

```
using namespace std;

std::string decomp(int n) {
    vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) v.push_back(i);

    auto e = v.end();
    for (auto b = v.begin(); b != e; b++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= (*b / 2); j++) {
            cout << "j" << j << endl;
            cout << "b" << *b << endl;

            if (*b % j == 0) {
                v.push_back(j);
                v.push_back(*b / j);
                v.erase(b);
                b--;
                e = v.end();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    string output;
    int max_value = *max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
    cout << "mv" << max_value << endl;

    for (int i = 2; i <= max_value; i++) {
        int count_of_this_element = count(v.begin(), v.end(), i);
        cout << "o" << count_of_this_element << endl;
        if (count_of_this_element == 1) output += to_string(i) + " * ";
        else if (count_of_this_element == 0) output += "";
        else output += to_string(i) + "^" + to_string(count_of_this_element) + " * ";
    }
    // output.erase(output.end());
    // output.erase(output.end());
    // output.erase(output.end());

    return output;
}

int main() {
    cout << decomp(14) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it, than I get this output:

```
j2
b4
j2
b5
j2
b6
j2
b7
j3
b7
j2
b8
j2
b9
j3
b9
j2
b10
j2
b11
j3
b11
j4
b11
j5
b11
j2
b12
j2
b13
j3
b13
j4
b13
j5
b13
j6
b13
j2
b14
j2
b234881038
j2
b39053
j3
b39053
j4
b39053
j5
b39053
j6
b39053
j7
b39053
j2
b9179272
j2
b9179864
j2
b1987727968
j2
b1987727968
j2
b1987727968
j2
b1988456824
j2
b1987728232
j2
b1987729392
j2
b1987729776
j2
b1988458632
```

My task is to make a vector of numbers from 1 to n, and than in a for-loop look for a non-prime numbers. When I find some non-prime number, then I decompose this number into its two integer components, push they back to the vector and delete the decomposed number.
But in output you can see, that when it comes to 14 (the biggest number) than the next number is "234881038". It appears that the number separators have been written to another memory location.
How can I get the numbers I've pushed back?

Comment: `b` and `e` are invalidated after `v.push_back(j)`, the code after that is illegal, results in undefined behavior.

Comment: The first problem I see is you are modifying your data array, while you are looping over it. You can't do it.

Comment: You'd better use (carefully...) a list here, because you can safely erase one element for a list without invalidating iterators - except when they point to the erased element, hence the advice to be careful

Answer (score 0):

This set of loops:

```
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) v.push_back(i);

    auto e = v.end();
    for (auto b = v.begin(); b != e; b++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= (*b / 2); j++) {
            cout << "j" << j << endl;
            cout << "b" << *b << endl;

            if (*b % j == 0) {
                v.push_back(j);
                v.push_back(*b / j);
                v.erase(b);
                b--;
                e = v.end();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Three bugs:

- Caching `e = v.end()` is unnecessary, but also problematic. As soon you invoke `push_back` or `erase`, the end position has changed. Just compare `b != v.end()` in your for loop.
- `v.erase(b)` followed by `b--` is odd at best and probably undefined behavior.   You just deleted `b` and then the code attempts to do iterator math on it.  You can get an updated iterator from the return value of erase.  Ala:

  `b = v.erase(b);`
- And even if you address both of the above, the `b` iterator will often become invalid (deleted) as soon as you invoke `v.push_back(j)`. And then it will crash again when it goes to calculate `*b/j`

We could attempt to put together a full set of fixes. But the above is still way too complicated for what you are trying to do.

How about this instead for calculating all the primes and nonprimes together:

```
std::vector<int> nonprimes;
std::vector<int> primes;

for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    bool isPrime = true;

    for (size_t j = 0; isPrime && j < primes.size(); j++) {
        isPrime = ((i % primes[j]) != 0);
    }

    if (isPrime) {
       primes.push_back(i);   
    } else {
        nonprimes.push_back(i);
    }
}
```

And then if you want to decompose a given non-prime number into its prime factors, you can do this:

```
vector<int> decomposed;
for (size_t k = 0; primes[k]*primes[k] <= n; k++) {
    if (n % primes[k] == 0) {
       decomposed.push_back(primes[k]);
    }
}
```